# jQuery text animation - text fade in

Tags: jquery

I looking for way to animate text with jQuery.

I want to display 'logging in...' message where 3 dots should be hidden on page load and after every lets say 300ms 1 dot to become visible. Which all together should create animation.

Is there any jQuery function created to do exact that or I will have to right my own?

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done rather nicely with a jQuery plugin. This makes it re-usable and configurable.

Something like this is simple enough. It has 3 defaults, which can be overriden

- **text** defaulted to "Loading"
- **numDots** the number of dots to count up to before recycling back to zero, defaults to 3
- **delay** the delay inbetween adding new dots. defaults to 300ms

  ```
  (function($) {

  $.fn.elipsesAnimation = function(options) {

      var settings = $.extend({}, { //defaults
          text: 'Loading',
          numDots: 3,
          delay: 300
      }, options);
      var currentText = "";
      var currentDots = 0;
      return this.each(function() {
          var $this = $(this);
          currentText = settings.text;
          $this.html(currentText);
          setTimeout(function() {
              addDots($this);
          }, settings.delay);
      });

      function addDots($elem) {
          if (currentDots >= settings.numDots) {
              currentDots = 0;
              currentText = settings.text;
          }
          currentText += ".";
          currentDots++;
          $elem.html(currentText);
          setTimeout(function() {
              addDots($elem);
          }, settings.delay);
      }
  }

  })(jQuery);
  ```

Usage could then be

```
// Writes "Hello World", counts  up to 10 dots with a 0.5second delay
$('#testDiv').elipsesAnimation ({text:"Hello World",numDots:10,delay:500});
```

And a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/6bbKk/

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Use with :

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
      //fadeIn your text, fake function for example
      FadeInMyText();

      setTimeout(function() {
        // fadeOut your text, fake function for example                           
        FadeOutMyText();
      }, 300);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery there is the delay(milliseconds, callback) function. You could use the callback function to orchestrate the delay. However for your purposes the [javascript window setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) would probably be more appropriate as you can run window.clearTimeout as soon as your loading is complete, resulting in a more responsive UI.

An example:

```
var timeoutId;

$(document).ready( function() {
    timeoutId = window.doTextUpdate(slowAlert, 2000);   
});

function doTextUpdate() {
    var current = $("#mytext").val();
    if(current.indexOf("...")) {
        $("#mytext").val("Loading");
    } else {
        $("#mytext").val(current + ".");
    }
}

function loadComplete() {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function(){launchAnimation('#animate');});

function launchAnimation(container){
    var cont = $(container);
    var i=0;
    setInterval(function(){
        ++i;
        if (i<4){
            var dot=jQuery("<span class='dot'>.</span>").appendTo(cont);
        }
        else{
            i=0;
            cont.find('.dot').remove();
        }
    },300);
}

</script>
<div id='animate' style='border:1px solid red'>Logging in</div>
```